# Proving a particular function is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I'm getting ready for an exam and I am having trouble with the following proof.
Let $f$ be a function, $f : N \to N$ , $f(x)  = [x,x+2014]$ , where $[a,b]$ is the smallest common multiple between $a$ and $b$.

a) Show that $f$ is injective

b) Show that N - f(N) is infinite

I've tried to find a function $g$ so that $g \circ f$ is injective, but with no success.

Comment: The standard way to show that a function $f$ is injective, and the first thing you should try, is not to find a function $g$ such that $g\circ f$ is injective (how do you show that $g\circ f$ is injective?) but to show that $f(a) = f(b)$ implies $a = b$, or the contrapositive.

Comment: Of course, that is obvious, but it is also obvious that there is a trick here, you can't just apply that method.

Comment: Hint: show that it's possible to find the value of $gcd(x, x+2014)$ from knowledge of $f(x)$.

Comment: Hmm, I was already on that track. Can you stay tuned and if I come up with anything tell me if it's wrong or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $[a,b]=\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$ and $2014=2\cdot 19\cdot 53$ is squarefree ,
we know that $$f(x)=\frac{x(x+2014)}{\gcd(x,x+2014)}=\frac{x(x+2014)}{\gcd(x,2014)}.$$
Since $\gcd(x,2014)$ is squarefree, its square divides the numerator, i.e. $\gcd(x,2014)$ divides $f(x)$. In fact any prime dividing $f(x)$ and $2014$ goes at least twice into the numerator and once into the denominator, so that we conclude $\gcd(x,2014)=\gcd(f(x),2014)$ and ultimately obtain
$$x(x+2014)=\gcd(x,f(x))f(x)$$
In other words, the function $g(x)= \gcd(x,2014)x$ gives us the injective function $g\circ f\colon x\mapsto x(x+2014)$, showing that $f$ is injective.

Since $\frac x{f(x)}=\frac{\gcd(x,2014)}{x+2014}$ and the numerator assumes only finitely many values whereas the denominator assumes infinitely many values, $\frac x{f(x)}$ assumes infinitely many different values.

Comment: Seems I really was on the right track but very far from proving it. I got stuck after showing that you could write gcd(x,x+2014) as just gcd(x,2014). Thanks.